# What is the proper way to clean up STOMP client in React useEffect?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, websocket, stomp

I'm using Strict mode so double rendering is causing there to be two socket connections opened by the following useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const socket = new SockJS(url);
    const clientObj=Stomp.over(socket);
    clientObj.connect({}, {}, openSocketCallback, closeSocketCallback);
    client.current=clientObj;
  }, []);
```

I tried to disconnect on dismount:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    const socket = new SockJS(url);
    const clientObj=Stomp.over(socket);
    clientObj.connect({}, {}, openSocketCallback, closeSocketCallback);
    client.current=clientObj;
    return ()=>{
      client.current.disconnect(()=>{
      });
    }
  }, []);
```

The connection has not actually been established yet, so I get an error: `InvalidStateError: The connection has not been established yet`

I understand the need to cleanup socket connections when component dismounts, but I can't figure out how to close the socket when it only finishes connecting sometime after the dismount has occurred.